# How to create a NSG to an existing subnet with terraform on azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am referencing existing subnet(s) as below, but I want a NSG to be created and attached to the subnet. It gives me error.

Code for refrencing and adding NSG is below:

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "tf-sn-erx-app" {
  name                 = "${var.subnet_app_name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.tf-vn-erx.name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"
  security_group       = "${azurerm_network_security_group.tf-nsg-erx-application.id}"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "tf-sn-erx-sql" {
  name                 = "${var.subnet_sql_name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.tf-vn-erx.name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"
  security_group       = "${azurerm_network_security_group.tf-nsg-erx-sql.id}"
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "tf-nsg-erx-application" {
  name                = "${var.application_nsg}"
  location            = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "tf-nsr-erx-application-5985" {
  name                        = "Open Port 5985"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "5985"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"
  network_security_group_name = "${azurerm_network_security_group.tf-nsg-erx-application.name}"
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "tf-nsr-erx-application-5986" {
  name                        = "Open Port 5986"
  priority                    = 101
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "5986"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"
  network_security_group_name = "${azurerm_network_security_group.tf-nsg-erx-application.name}"
}
```

However, when I do run, terraform, below error is reported.

```
Error: data.azurerm_subnet.tf-sn-erx-app: : invalid or unknown key: security_group
Error: data.azurerm_subnet.tf-sn-erx-sql: : invalid or unknown key: security_group
```

What is the issue?

Comment: @CharlesXu and BMW, apologies for the delay. I was on Easter break. Got it working as below:
```
network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.tf-nsg-erx-application.id}"
```

Comment: So should I post that as answer then, it certainly works. I have all NI's are associated with IP's now.

Comment: If you use things in my answer, then you should mark it instead of adding another one. You get the answer from me and return the mark to me.

Comment: Any more update?

Comment: @CharlesXu appreciate your persistence with passion! I have posted the answer, at least that worked for me. Thank you to you and BMW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BMW says, there is no property `security_group` in the data `azurerm_subnet`. If you want to associate an NSG to the existing subnet, you can use [`azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/subnet_network_security_group_association.html) to achieve that. Just use the data `azurerm_subnet` to refer your existing subnet and create an NSG for it or use the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by the below code:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf-ni-erx-mkconn" {
 count                     = 3
 name                      = "${var.mkconn_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-nic01"
 location                  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.location}"
 resource_group_name       = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"
 network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.tf-nsg-erx-application.id}"
```

Comment: If this is the solution, why do you question how to create an NSG to the existing subnet?! This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @CharlesXu I figured it out after I posted the question. I can attached some screenshots. It surely works.

Comment: Yeah, it works. But it shows that the NSG associated with the NIC. You can also associate the NSG with the subnet as your question.

Comment: Ok which one should be followed. NSG to NIC or to subnet following best security practices, can you kindly advise me please?

Comment: They're all practices, just for your choose. To subnet, it's for all service in the subnet. To NIC, it's just for one which it associated to.

Comment: I have voted as the correct answer in favour of actual question. My issue is resolved in the way I have provided as answer.

Comment: But if you want to manage the NSG rules altogether for all the services in the subnet, you should try the NSG to the subnet.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesXu for the lead. I shall explore that way. They don't have a clear view of architecture.

Answer (score 1):

There is no key of `security_group` in data source `azurerm_subnet`

```
Argument Reference
name - (Required) Specifies the name of the Subnet.
virtual_network_name - (Required) Specifies the name of the Virtual Network this Subnet is located within.
resource_group_name - (Required) Specifies the name of the resource group the Virtual Network is located in.
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subnet.html

Comment: I guess what he is saying - you should remove that key :)

Comment: @4c74356b41 yes